# How to keep IdentityServer Access Token expiration in sync with cookie expiration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth, identityserver3

I have set up identity server 3 in line with the mvc api sample.
However, I am finding that while the cookie expiration is working with a sliding expiration the access token expiration is not being updated.
This results in our api being called with authentication, but the external api  comes back as un-authentication.

My current work arround is to call an IFrame periodically that will forcibly return 401 and thus go through the rebuilding of the cookie and user claims.

Is there a better way to keep the access token up to date as my solution seems wrong.